# how can i scroll to first td empty

Tags: jquery

i have not having any luck with this , and i cant even seem to get a class added to the first empty td cell , in order to even try to get it to scroll

jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/16/

I need to add a class to the first empty td cell , then i would like on pageload to have the div scroll to that empty cell

but i can not even get step one working

```
$( "td:empty" ).addClass( "scrollhere" );
```

and this

```
if ($('td').text().trim() == ""){
  $(this).addClass('scrollhere');
}
```

and this

```
if ((td.children().length == 0) && td.text().trim() == ""){
  $(this).addClass('scrollhere');
}
```

the td info is dynamically added and appears when i copied the source html , there is a html space being added to empty td's " "

Comment: None of your `<td>`s are empty.

Comment: `$(this)` does not refer to each `td`

Comment: [If your `<td>`s are *actually* empty, your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/20/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TD's are not empty; they contain `&nbsp;`

you need to add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td:empty").addClass("scrollhere");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollhere").offset().top
    }, 2*1000); // <-- in miliseconds (2 seconds, update if you want to scroll faster)
});
```

See Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/19/

**UPDATE**
if you cannot modify the html, then use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').each(function (i, elem) {

        if ($(elem).html().trim() === '&nbsp;') {
            $(elem).addClass("scrollhere");
        }
    });

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollhere:first()").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

See demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/30/

**UPDATE 2**

If you only want to update the first empty `TD` then use a flag like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var foundOne = false;

    $('td').each(function (i, elem) {
        if ($(elem).html().trim() === '&nbsp;' && !foundOne) {
            $(elem).addClass("scrollhere");
            foundOne = true;
            return;
        }
    });

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollhere:first()").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Updated demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/35/

Comment: ochi , i added some HTML to match my existing site , and applied your solution. My container is set to fixed height and set overflow to scroll , and now the solution you had will not auto scroll to the td within the div  http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/51/ - can you assist further ?

Comment: This should really be another separate question.  I don't have a lot of time right now but here's a quick fix for it http://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/65/ - it is a bit hackish but it may work for you for the time being.  If you add another question, let me know so I can spend more time on it later today when I have a bit more time

Answer (score 5):

As i19 said, non of your TD are empty. You have &nbsp in every TD ceil. 
Try to remove that   and your jquery addClass function will work properly.
After that add jquery animate method call with scrollTop parameter

```
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".scrollhere").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

EDIT:
Try to remove nbsp with this code:

```
$("td").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''));});
```

once you remove nbsp then try to scroll with previous.

Keep in mind this will remove &nbsp from all TD elements

Comment: What if the `&nbsp;` characters are deliberate?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, and what I said in the response that will remove all &nbsp from TD ceils

Comment: the the Robbie Averill solution. It's perfect

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter()` and `.text()` (which won't return `&nbsp;` characters) to apply your class:

```
$("td")
    .filter(function() {
        return ($(this).text() === '');
    })
    .addClass("scrollhere");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/29/) (using [Wlada's animation example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31954711/2812842))

Comment: This is best solution, I think

Comment: Only the first one? add `.eq(0)` before the `.addClass()` call

Comment: Or you could only add the class to the first match in the filter, like the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxwd0qp0/37/

Answer (score 0):

This should set the focus.

```
$('table:td:empty:eq(0)').focus();
```

This should set the class

```
  $('table:td:empty:eq(0)').attr('class','className');
```

Comment: Huh? That doesn't apply the class to each element.

Comment: Got too excited Robbie.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have control to change the html being generated to this report , i have no idea why the html space is being added , so i need to look for first empty td or first td with only html space